# Building for Mac OS 10.6 results in error "In [..]/libZonicKRM.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, osx-snow-leopard

I'm updating application for Mac OS X 10.6 and getting this error. I believe that means Kagi/Zonic KRM module doesn't support 64-bit? So I can't build my app as 64-bit, right?

Is there anyone who use Zonic KRM under Snow Leopard?..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it.

The latest version is from Feb 2009 and is 10.3.9 compatible so looks like it has not been compiled recently.

I would contact the autours.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Mark, you should contact Kagi and see if they have something updated to offer. Something similar happened with Kagi's embedded library during the transition to i386:

http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/85/kagi-universal

For me, it turned out to be one example of many where it's ultimately not worth the risk of embedding compiled code that you can't compile/fix yourself. I no longer depend upon the Kagi stuff, for a variety of reasons.